# Find the set of points in $\mathbb{C}$ s.t. $|z| = Rez + 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers

I was given the above problem as a homework question and I've arrived at a solution but I am not sure if my approach is the best one or even a valid one. Any help would be great!

Consider $z = a + bi : a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a = Rez, b = Imz$. Then we would like $|z| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = a + 1 = Rez + 1.$ To arrive at this, we require $|z| = \sqrt{(a+1)^2} = \sqrt{a^2 + 2a + 1}$, which means $b = \sqrt{2a+1}$ so that $|z| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = \sqrt{a^2 + \sqrt{2a+1}^2} = \sqrt{a^2 + 2a + 1} = \sqrt{(a+1)^2} = a + 1 = Rez + 1$. We also require $2a+1 > 0$ or $a > \frac{-1}{2}.$

This gives us the set $\{a + bi : a > \frac{-1}{2}, b = \sqrt{2a + 1}\}$

Comment: I think it's good!

Comment: You are right sir

Comment: Isn't $a\geqslant-\dfrac12$?

Comment: `\Re(z)` $\Re(z)$ `\operatorname{Re}z` $\operatorname{Re}z$ `\Im(z)` $\Im(z)$ and `\operatorname{Im}z` $\operatorname{Im}z$ are good to keep in your MathJax toolbox.

Comment: please note that at the last part $$2a+1\ge0\therefore a\ge-\frac{1}{2}$$
you also need to keep in mind that $$a+1\ne\sqrt{\left(a+1\right)^2}$$ but $$|a+1|=\sqrt{\left(a+1\right)^2}\therefore b=\pm\sqrt{2a+1}$$

Comment: @Holo this is crucial! Thank you for pointing this out

Comment: @student_t np!!

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = \sqrt{a^2 + 2a + 1} \implies \color{red}{b^2 = 2a + 1} \implies b=\color{red}{\pm} \sqrt{2a+1}$.

Comment: Yes of course, silly mistake!